# KVNProgress not working under UIPageViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, hud, kvnprogress

Here is my code under `viewDidLoad` method of a single ViewController as a child of my PageViewController.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

    [super viewDidLoad];

    [KVNProgress showWithStatus:@"Loading"]; // Not shown on child vc, see attached screen shot

    [[DataManager sharedInstance]getWeatherReportForPlace:@"Kolkata" completionBLock:^(WeatherReport *report, NSError *error) {

        [KVNProgress showSuccessWithStatus:@"Success"];

    }];
}
```

If I add `[KVNProgress showWithStatus:@"Loading"];` inside `completionBlock` then it's working but it is only showing success.

But I want a Loading until the completion Block finish it's execution.For that I need to put the `[KVNProgress showWithStatus:@"Loading"];` outside `completionBlock`.

Here is my scenario

[image]

Comment: why are you doing all of this on viewDidLoad? Can't you separate this logic in a separate method and try the same.

Comment: The main problem what I could suspect for now is you are not doing stuff in proper threads, on what thread does the DataManager class execute?

Comment: Thanks @satheeshwaran, finally embedding  `[KVNProgress showWithStatus:@"Loading"];` in main thread with `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
        //Run UI Updates
        [KVNProgress showWithStatus:@"Loading"];
    });` solved the problem.